# Any issues with *really* long series of hoppers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need to transport about 30 double chests of material about 1000 meters in single player minecraft.

I was thinking of building some sort of permanent transportation system to accomplish this.

I prefer dirt simple (but potentially resource heavy) contraptions over complicated "efficient" contraptions.

Because of this, I was thinking of just setting up a string of 1000 hoppers in a row, to move the material from one place to another.

My question:  What will happen at the loaded/unloaded chunks with such a setup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I take back my earlier post.

### [Hoppers will transport items **through** unloaded chunks!](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/16w1s4/hoppers_can_transport_items_through_unloaded/)

> I've built another test pipe far away from spawn and made it really long (1000 hoppers). Now when i put an item in the first hopper, wait 5 minutes and then teleport to the end, the item will sit there in the last hopper. However if i put the item in the first hopper, then immediately teleport to the end and wait there, nothing happens. I waited for like 30 minutes but the item didn't arrive.
>
> So apparently a hopper pipe can transport items into or through unloaded chunks, but there are certain limitations. I guess if a hopper tries to push an item into an adjacent unloaded chunk, minecraft will at least load the containers/hoppers of said chunk. So my test setup would cause something like a chain reaction of chunks getting loaded (at least partially, items still won't despawn in those chunks).
>
> If i immediately teleport to the end however, minecraft will unload the chunk containing the item, so no hopper will try to load the next chunk.

Comment: "*Hoppers won't see hoppers in unloaded chunks as a valid source*" [is false](http://youtu.be/9G8HxjOqr94?t=23m35s).

Comment: @BlaXpirit Hmmm, I guess that was a case I wasn't worried about.  I'm wondering about the other case, does a hopper in a loaded chunk just fill up and not transfer to the unloaded chunk hopper?

Comment: According to This video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdtUJobQaQ8 all sorts of things could cause a chunk to be loaded, but the only thing that can unload a chunk is a player who walks away from the loaded chunk.